# googleyolo.retrieve() is always showing google signin iframe on reload

Tags: single-sign-on, google-signin, google-identity

I expected googleyolo.retrieve() to automatically signin, but it's showing the iframe to ask permission/to select the user every time.

Here is [my code](https://pastebin.com/ApQsZyts) it should work via localhost
This is my retrieve promise

```
    const retrievePromise = googleyolo.retrieve({
      supportedAuthMethods: [
        "https://accounts.google.com",
         "googleyolo://id-and-password"
      ],
      supportedIdTokenProviders: [
        {
          uri: "https://accounts.google.com",
          clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        }
      ]
    });
```

It's working fine,but the login iframe is popuping everytime

Comment: Can you check that auto sign-in is enabled for all your accounts at passwords.google.com ?

Comment: I have enabled for all the accounts, If single account is logged in, a popup in the right top is appearing and it is auto signing in. But if there are multiple accounts, the iframe is appearing everytime and I need to select an account.

Comment: I had this same issue, so I had to also implement gapi before googleyolo to workaround this. so the workflow would be to use gapi to login the user if there's already an active account already logged in to the site. If there isn't, then googleyolo takes over the login process. I would love to know if there's a way to automatically login the user when there are multiple active accounts using googleyolo.

Comment: Currently, there is no way to automatically login when there are multiple users. I read the same in one of the  @StevenSoneff answer, he is product manager at Google for Yolo